# Publish annual Q&A journal

Tags: feature-request, publishing

I was thinking of asking the moderators to publish a journal annually, containing the best 100 questions of the year, and their detailed discussion sessions, so that if someone searches for a particular topic 6 years later, it shows up in the journal, along with its detailed discussion.

Comment: i mean, we can do that even now, but we may have to go through 4-5 similar questions with varying answers, which often takes a lot of time.

Comment: What about the newspaper?

Comment: WHat newspaper?

Comment: I'm curious, what "detailed discussion" are you talking about? (oh, and regarding newsletters: https://stackexchange.com/newsletters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a lot of work to ask the moderators to do. However there's nothing to stop you from doing it if you think it's a worthwhile undertaking. I have to say that it's not obvious to me that this would be especially useful.

Comment: I feel fairly comfortable saying on behalf of the mods that we won't do it for exactly this reason: it's a lot of work, it doesn't seem terribly useful to us, and it could just as easily be done by someone else who _does_ think it useful.

Comment: IS it possible for the mods to arrange for a 'print page' button for each question?

Comment: Copy pasting manually will be gruesome for a normal user.

Comment: @Lelouch: Doesn't `ctrl+p` work for you?

Comment: like i didnt even know such a feature existed . Sorry for the trouble then. Ill delete the question.

Comment: oh sorry ... i cant do that either.

Comment: @Lelouch Neither the mods nor Stack Exchange are going to do that for you, but *someone* already did: http://www.stackprinter.com/ (which is better than the print page feature of your browser). Just an example of how using a open license for the content here lets third parties add more value.

Comment: I seem to recall that there is an add-on that connects the print shortcut of your browser to StackPrinter,, but I can't guarantee it and don't have a pointer.